# Opening a specific file extension

Tags: android, android-intent

It is quite incredible how I could not find a simple solution to this question.

I am using the following code to obtain a file URI in my app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I would like the dialog that opens to show files with a specific file extension (*.orcsc) only

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

It can't. Android does not use file extensions much, and there is little support for it. Moreover, `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` is designed around content, not files, and there is no requirement for content in a cloud storage provider to have a filename.

You are welcome to constrain by MIME type, replacing `*/*` with something that would be of relevance. Otherwise, see if there is a [file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created) that better fits your needs.